# Where can I find documents describing exact algorithms many numerical linear algebra packages use?

Tags: python, numpy, package, numeric, lapack

My (general) question is whether I can find documents describing exact algorithms many numerical linear algebra packages use, and if so, how (or where) I can find them.

For example, I want to know which algorithm Python function, `numpy.linalg.eigh`, uses. This [reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html) doesn't describe or even mention specific algorithms, but says it (internally) uses `LAPACK` routines, `_syevd` and `_heevd`. Then where can I find which algorithms `_syevd` and `_heevd` use.

I know that you can use, e.g., Jacobi methods for eigenvalue decompostion for symmetric matrices and that you can use, e.g., Lanczos methods for eigenvalue decomposition for positive definite matrices. But I can't find documents describing specifically which algorithms each of those functions use.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried looking though the documentation and source code of LAPACK, as suggested?

Comment: some link that might be useful:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src
https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/

Comment: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thx for your information. But I did find the source files, but I'm not able to dicypher source code well. So i was looking for documents mentioned something like, "eigh uses Jacobi methods. The peudo code for that is like this" like what's written in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm#The_algorithm . But, hpaulj may have provided me what I wanted. Let me check it and get back to you soon. Thx again!

Comment: @simoneviozzi The same comments  as the one above for you. I really appreciated your help.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks a lot! let me review the documents and get back to you. There's high probability that this document is what I want. :) Let me spend some time reading it. Thx a lot!